# Issue pushing to Heroku due to JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, stripe-payments

I'm attempting to update my app on heroku, but am getting an error. Everything works fine locally, and have had no trouble pushing in the past.

Here is the error output I receive in terminal:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
   I, [2014-05-23T19:57:06.803597 #1447]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/public/assets/Rave-76af238e2f8042f0df74239e340676aa.jpg
   I, [2014-05-23T19:57:06.805675 #1447]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/public/assets/social-dccb3b82dfc09e0f163a4ae48f971508.png
   I, [2014-05-23T19:57:06.810665 #1447]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/public/assets/tables-a706161a3475c7eb419119162d0da280.jpg
   rake aborted!
   ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: string (formatCardNumber) (line: 13889, col: 33, pos: 390151)
   Error
   at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20140523-1447-8yjrbp.js:2357:10754)
   at js_error (/tmp/execjs20140523-1447-8yjrbp.js:2357:10973)
   at croak (/tmp/execjs20140523-1447-8yjrbp.js:2357:19198)
   at token_error (/tmp/execjs20140523-1447-8yjrbp.js:2357:19335)
   at unexpected (/tmp/execjs20140523-1447-8yjrbp.js:2357:19423)
   at semicolon (/tmp/execjs20140523-1447-8yjrbp.js:2357:19896)
   at simple_statement (/tmp/execjs20140523-1447-8yjrbp.js:2357:22669)
   at /tmp/execjs20140523-1447-8yjrbp.js:2357:20665
   at /tmp/execjs20140523-1447-8yjrbp.js:2357:20069
   at block_ (/tmp/execjs20140523-1447-8yjrbp.js:2357:24688)
   (in /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)/tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:68:in `extract_result'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:41:in `compile_to_tempfile'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `exec'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.5.0/lib/uglifier.rb:186:in `really_compile'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.5.0/lib/uglifier.rb:110:in `compile'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:25:in `evaluate'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in define'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
   /tmp/build_9c1d18a8-5bbf-41e8-ad98-48e938516c9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in define'
```

I'm curious if this has something to do with my payment.js file. That is the only place in my app I have 'FormatCardNumber' referenced. Is heroku not digesting this Jquery?

Comment: Have you tried compiling your assets locally? `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, commit the files and then push to heroku

Comment: It worked, but none of my images got moved to the site (background and logo)- how do I move them?

Comment: They should've been automatically compiled as well.  Are you storing them somewhere other than app/assets/images?

Comment: check out: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html specifically section 2.3.  Make sure your images are compiled by checking the public folder and that you are calling them properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to clean your assets and then precompile:

```
rake assets:clean
```

Then precompile:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Then add -A, commit, and push to heroku.

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Precompiled assets"
git push heroku master
```